# How can I get the Davies-Bouldin Index for clusters in a graph in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a graph that is formed of different connected components, each connected component represents a cluster. I am trying to get the Davies-Bouldin Index, Calinski-Harabasz, and Silhouette coefficient for the clusters. I am not sure if this is possible as usually built in clustering methods like the k-means algorithms are used (here clustering is done in a totally different code). Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
from sklearn.metrics import davies_bouldin_score, calinski_harabasz_score, silhouette_score
import numpy as np

#the first part of my code removes the needed edges for the graph to have the desired clusters, my testing shows it works fine
with open("graph.txt", "r") as file:
    edge_list1 = [tuple(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in file]


with open("edits.txt", "r") as file:
    edge_list2 = [tuple(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in file]

edges_to_remove = set(edge_list2)

filtered_edge_list1 = [edge for edge in edge_list1 if edge not in edges_to_remove]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(filtered_edge_list1)

clusters = list(nx.connected_components(G))

# Assigning labels in clusters, they are unlabelled since the original data is just a graph with no extra information, my edge list starts from 1 so I use labels[node-1]
labels = np.zeros(G.number_of_nodes(), dtype=int)
for cluster_idx, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
    for node in cluster:
        labels[node-1] = cluster_idx


davies_bouldin_index = davies_bouldin_score(G.nodes(), labels)

calinski_harabasz_index = calinski_harabasz_score(G.nodes(), labels)

silhouette_coefficient = silhouette_score(G.nodes(), labels)

print("Davies-Bouldin Index:", davies_bouldin_index)
print("Calinski-Harabasz Index:", calinski_harabasz_index)
print("Silhouette Coefficient:", silhouette_coefficient)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    davies_bouldin_index = davies_bouldin_score(G.nodes(), labels)
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_param_validation.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/_unsupervised.py", line 403, in davies_bouldin_score
    X, labels = check_X_y(X, labels)
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1147, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 940, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1 2 3 4 5 6].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

This error arises from having `G.nodes()` as input, I tried using the variable clusters as input (which makes more sense) and I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    davies_bouldin_index = davies_bouldin_score(clusters, labels)
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_param_validation.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/_unsupervised.py", line 403, in davies_bouldin_score
    X, labels = check_X_y(X, labels)
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1147, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "/home/sergio/PycharmProjects/3CCED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 940, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[{1, 2, 3} {4, 5, 6}].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

It is not clear what I should give as input, any help would be appreciared